# Getting css / html properties of chrome find window

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm trying to built a window that would look very similar to the chrome find (ctrl + f) window.

I tried looking at the source of the chrome browser but couldn't find where the css / html content is at.

Is it possible to view / get the html and css source of the find window (or the print dialog). If so, how?

Comment: Chrome's UI isn't written with HTML and CSS

Comment: are you sure? it seems as though there's quite a lot of css and html there. and I am somewhat doubtful that the search dialog is written in c. though I guess that in the basis it's c or something similar

Comment: for example - https://github.com/darwin/chromium-src-chrome-browser/blob/f5a7c3f8bfb532c4907c14410ed2dfd4af3a51ba/resources/options/search_box.html